# Using multiple prediction heads with a neural network in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, nlp

I have a tensorflow network with 5 layers. My training data has several target columns I want to predict, but in any given example, some of the target columns may not be there. My dataset is relatively small (145k text examples), so I want to get maximum training use out of every example, even if it doesn't contain one of the targets.

So my plan was to use transfer learning for this. I did the following:

1. Train the entire network on my most-populated target column
2. Remove the last layer from the network (the prediction head) and save it separately
3. Add a fresh, untrained final layer to the pre-trained body of the remaining 4 layers. So now I have 4 trained layers and 1 untrained layer.
4. Train this layer on the next target column.
5. Break it apart again and save both pieces, overwriting the 'body' with the more heavily trained body, and saving the head separately.

So if an example has target A but not target B, I still get some useful learning on the general lingo of my dataset while training on A that can be useful later on B. This worked! Both target A and target B can be effectively predicted with the resulting network.

Now I am attempting to use this system for inference, so my method is:

1. Load the body and all the heads.
2. Prep my data to the input specs of the body
3. Cycle through the heads, making a prediction for each target

This also mostly works, but I get the following error and I don't know what (if anything) to do about it:

WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at 0x7fbe6c5c6730> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

None of these seem to apply to my situation.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: This is not an error message, just a warning (that is why it starts with WARNING:)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am planning to scale this solution to handle large numbers of requests, so if this operation is very expensive, I'd love to do it in a less expensive way.